# How to sort children of an element in XmlDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I've an XML document of type System.Xml.XmlDocument as following:

```
<root>

  <group>
    <dog order="1" />
    <cat order="4" />
    <cat order="3" />
    <dog order="7" />
    <dog order="5" />
    <cat order="6" />
    <dog order="2" />
  </group>

  <other/>

</root>
```

I want it to be like

```
<root>

  <group>
    <dog order="1" />
    <dog order="2" />
    <cat order="3" />
    <cat order="4" />
    <dog order="5" />
    <cat order="6" />
    <dog order="7" />
  </group>

  <other/>

</root>
```

I've tried various codes online but none of them is working for me. I've also converted my XmlDocument to XDocument to work with LINQ as follows:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xdoc.OuterXml);
```

yet still no success.

I need to sort children inside group element XmlDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to remove the elements and add them again after sorting.

```
XDocument doc  = XDocument.Load(filename);
var elements = doc.Root.Element("group").Elements().ToList();  // Copy the elements.

doc.Root.Element("group").RemoveAll();                         // Remove the elements from the document.
doc.Root.Element("group").Add(elements.OrderBy(x=>int.Parse(x.Attribute("order").Value)));
//Add them again after sorting.
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O7VrUJ)

**Output**

```
 <root>
  <group>
    <dog order="1" />
    <dog order="2" />
    <cat order="3" />
    <cat order="4" />
    <dog order="5" />
    <cat order="6" />
    <dog order="7" />
  </group>
</root>
```

Comment: Its great bro. Demo seems to be working perfect. I'm gonna use this code. Once all set up, I'll mark this answer. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

try this XSLT:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="dog">
                            <xsl:sort select="@aa" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then apply it::

```
XPathDocument myDocXPath = new XPathDocument(myXml);
XslTransform myXslTrans = new XslTransform();
myXslTrans.Load(myStyleSheet);
XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter("result.xml",null);
myXslTrans.Transform(myDocXPath, null, myWriter);
```

Comment: I appreciate you responded. But I really don't have any idea what this piece of code would do? I got this xml in xDoc and I just want to sort the group element inside it and put it back to xDoc.

Comment: applying XSLT should sort you xml and then you have to write it some other XML(this will be sorted)

Comment: What if I don't wanna write result.xml?

Comment: you can try xml to Linq XDocument ip = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/data.xml"));
var op = ip.Descendants("Column")
    .Where(node => node.Attribute("IsHidden").Value == "false")
    .OrderBy(node => int.Parse(node.Attribute("Position").Value))
    .ToList();